# How i could decode byte string to store in string variable without null bytes and human readable?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, decode, iso-8859-1

I read some lines from a textfile which was in a zip file and have to modified to a readable string.
for example one line i get from file show like this:

```
byte_code = b"\x000\x002\x002\x008\x007\x00:\x00,\x00'\x001\x004\x00.\x001\x002\x00.\x002\x000\x001\x009\x00 \x002\x000\x00:\x002\x008\x00:\x002\x007\x00'\x00,\x00$\x000\x001\x00F\x00B\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00\r\x00\n"
```

if i decode and print it, i get a readabel result (sory the output have some null byte in it and i could not enter her

```
print(byte_code.decode('latin-1'))
```

i would to get the readable result like the print function got into a normal string variable without null bytes in it
this line i expect

```
02287:,'14.12.2019 20:28:27',$01FB,,,,
```

but if i assign the decode line to a string variable i get this one not readable string

```
mystr = byte_code.decode('latin-1')
mystr
Out[55]: "\x000\x002\x002\x008\x007\x00:\x00,\x00'\x001\x004\x00.\x001\x002\x00.\x002\x000\x001\x009\x00 \x002\x000\x00:\x002\x008\x00:\x002\x007\x00'\x00,\x00$\x000\x001\x00F\x00B\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00\r\x00\n"
```

Is the decoding of byte string with the correct encoding format?
How i get the correct readable string without null bytes?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the perfect answer, but it might be a quick solution until something better comes up.

```
byteLine = b"\xff\xfe0" + byte_code + b"\x00"

strLine = byteLine.decode('utf16')
```

The strLine value is then:

```
    In [1] : strLine
    Out[2] : "002287:,'14.12.2019 20:28:27',$01FB,,,,\r\n"
```

Comment: Do you know a possibility do decode the byte string directly without adding the string components?